# Importing Orange gives me this error message: "ImportError: No module named Orange"

Tags: python, orange

I'm trying to install Orange on my laptop, and it gives me this error message when I type:

> import Orange
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> ImportError: No module named Orange

I've checked other answers, and my path seems to have the Orange directory in it, and I'm using a capital letter. It worked perfectly fine on the desktop, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Also, Orange Canvas won't even open, which I assume is a related issue to this but I may be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the results from sys.path:

> 'C:\windows\system32\python27.zip', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\orng', 'C:\csvn\Python25\DLLs', 'C:\csvn\Python25\lib', 'C:\csvn\Python25\lib\plat-win', 'C:\csvn\Python25\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin', 'C:\csvn\Python25', 'C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages', 'C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\csvn\Python25\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin'

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a Python 2.7 package with Python 2.5?

Comment: I installed 2.7. Not sure why the path refers to 2.5. Good catch, I'm not sure how I missed that. Let me see if I can fix that and fix the problem.

Comment: Further clarification on this, I uninstalled everything Python related and started over. When I try to re-install Orange it tells me Python isn't installed and installs Python 2.7.2 for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module name is orange with a little o.
Python is case sensitive so Orange != orange (as are most other programming languages).

RTM http://orange.biolab.si/doc/ofb/start.htm
:)

```
import orange
```

Comment: When I type it in lowercase it gives me the same error except it says "No module named Orange.orange" at the end.

Comment: You're correct.  Problem here is that orange seems to have changed the way they do things.

Comment: On further investigation this looks like being weirdness with the orange library itself.

See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861698/importing-orange-returns-importerror-no-module-named-orange
and
http://orange.biolab.si/forum/viewtopic.php?t=945

It appears that they've made some changes invalidating existing code.
http://orange.biolab.si/blog/2011/12/20/orange-25-code-conversion/

Comment: You've got 2.7 paths mixed in with your 2.5 paths.  You're very likely to have weirdness unless you pick a version of python and change your sys path to only include that version. 

Also what dir is orange installed in?  If it's in C:\Python27\lib\site-packages you need that in your path.

Comment: Thanks - I have no idea how it ended up that way. I used the same Orange Installer I did on the desktop so I'm not sure why it gave me this weirdness. I'll try editing the path and hopefully it will fix it.

Comment: This worked - thanks demented hedgehog! I went into System Properties > Environmental Variables, edited some of the Python variables and then created a new one called PYTHONPATH and it works. Thank you so much for your help!